# Why does it take so long for background color to change?

Tags: sockets, python-2.7, wxpython, python-multithreading

I am running into a problem with a simple program that changes the color of the background when it receives a command from a different machine through TCP. It takes like thirty seconds to change the color. I am running this through the local network so it should be near instant response. I am using wxPython for the frame. I don't think I have overly complicated code. Relevant code:

```
    threader=threading.Thread(target=self.threading)
    threader.start()
def threading(self):
    host="192.168.1.122"
    port=4100
    s=socket.socket()
    s.bind((host,port))
    s.listen(1)
    c,addr=s.accept()
    print "Connected"
    while 1:
        data=c.recv(1024)
        if not data:
            break
        data=data.split("_")
        reading=int(data[1])
        pin=int(data[0])
        if pin == 1:
            if reading<20:
                self.front_left.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 2:
            if reading<20:
                self.front_right.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 3:
            if reading<20:
                self.bottom_left.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        elif pin == 4:
            if reading<20:
                self.bottom_right.SetBackgroundColour("red")
        else:
            pass
    c.close()
```

I need this code to be instant as this will be going on a robot that will tell if objects are too close(which is why there is red background when it gets within 20 cm of object). Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears that you are attempting to update wxPython code from a thread. This action is unsupported / undefined in wxPython. You need to use thread-safe methods to update the wxPython UI, such as wx.CallAfter or wx.PostEvent. See the following wxPython wiki page for some examples:

- http://wiki.wxpython.org/LongRunningTasks

Basically, you'll want to do something like this in your **if** statements:

```
wx.CallAfter(self.bottom_right.SetBackgroundColour, "red")
```

Comment: Also, in some cases the bacjground may not appear to have been changed until the window is repainted, so if the above does not seem to help you may want to move the SetBackgroundColour to a new method, which also calls Refresh, and then call that new method via wx.CallAfter.

Comment: Good point. I should have mentioned the **Refresh()** method.